# difference between git ignore and untrack

Tags: git, gitignore

What's the difference between ignore a folder and untrack in git? I need to remove some folders from my git repository and I am working in Netbeans with the git plugins and put by mistake the build, dist, and nbproject folders in my repository and now I need to remove those folders.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

If you create a file in your repository named .gitignore, git will use its rules when looking at files to commit. git will not ignore a file that was already tracked (i.e. was in the repo) before a rule was added to this file to ignore it. File must be un-tracked (removed from the repo) using

```
git rm --cached filename
```

The command will stop tracking but keep the file there intact.

Answer (score 14):

By "ignore" I assume you mean `.gitignore`, which is a special file you can make that `git` will read to determine a set of files and/or directories to ignore. You can override this, but generally these files will be hidden from any `git` operation.

"Untracked" in `git` just means that you haven't added the file to the repository yet.

If a file is untracked and excluded by the `.gitignore`, you won't even see it via `git status` or any other `git` command.

To solve your current problem, where you have already accidentally added files that you do not want to track and want to ignore, first add those folders to your `.gitignore` and then try this command:

```
git rm -r --cached "path/to/ignored/directories"
```

This will remove the undesired directories from your repo but will not delete them from your local working copy.

Comment: Thanks for explaining what "untracked" means.

Answer (score 1):

You will want to use untrack instead of gitignore as gitignore won't affect files that are currently being tracked. http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore

Comment: You're not explaining what tracking is though.